# Cant target element using css first-child/nth-child?

Tags: html, css, selector, target

Please refer to this page:
http://www.newsweekgradplus.com/Business/Degree/Accounting

if you look at the middle column, the first 4 boxes are grey and after that in white.

What I want to do is add a horizontal line btween the grey and the white rectangle
but i cant seem to target it.

Comment: Is it always grey results first? in that case you could put just a top border on the whites: `border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;`

Comment: nope the listing is dynamic, some will have grey but some doesn't

Comment: Please show some code in your question, or set up a jsfiddle, so your question remains relevant to others after you fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will make any white box preceded by `br` and a gray box will have a (black) border on top of it.

```
.mbaBox+br+.mbaBox-white {
    position: relative;
}

.mbaBox+br+.mbaBox-white:after {
    content: " ";
    background: #000; /* your color */
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With selector `.mbaBox+br+.mbaBox-white` you will get the first white box after gray box, custom your css for this element :).

Have fun !

Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp